# Key must be pushed at an angle

Tags: keyboard

Ive just recently started having this problem, but whenever I need to use my “r” key, I have to push it at an angle or else it doesn’t work. And by this I mean I have to push down and forwards or down and back. It does not work if I push it straight down. Ive tried removing the key cap and cleaning the board but nothing works. I use a rk71 red switch.

Comment: Replace the swtich?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue, and the solution is likely to replace the key and/or the switch.